# MATLAB : How to plot pdf

Tags: matlab, plot, distribution, probability-density

I want to plot the following on the same piece of paper.

The pdf of exponential distribution with parameter 5
The pdf of t distribution with parameter 15

I don't know how to draw the pdf but know how to plot several figure on the same piece of paper by using command `subplot()`

Comment: if you define some x, e.g. x = linspace(-10,10,1e3); then you could calculate pdf(x) and plot it. Which step isn't clear for you?

Comment: @Chris `x=linspace(-10,10,1e3),pdf = exppdf(x,10),plot(pdf)` .  Is that right? The figure seems something wrong.

Comment: Well, it's just that the exponential distribution is defined for x >= 0. Other than that you can also try plot(x,pdf).

Answer (score 0):

**Method 1: Use built-in functions**  (requires Statistics toolbox)
Using [`exppdf()`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/exppdf.html) and [`tpdf()`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/tpdf.html) is easy but requires the Statistics Toolbox. If you don't have those functions then you can always directly code the PDF functions ([Student's t](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Student%27s_t-distribution) and [Exponential](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_distribution)) as in Method 2 below.

Note that MATLAB parameterizes the Exponential distribution by the mean which is the inverse of the rate (`lambda`).

```
lambda = 5;     
nu = 15;

Xrng = 0:.01:2;
Yrng = -5:.01:5;    

figure
subplot(1,2,1)
plot(Xrng,exppdf(Xrng,1/lambda),'k-')
subplot(1,2,2)
plot(Yrng,tpdf(Yrng,nu),'b-')
```

**Method 2: Hard-code PDF functions directly** (no toolbox required)
You can always directly code the PDF functions ([Student's t](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Student%27s_t-distribution) and [Exponential](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_distribution)).

```
fexph =@(x) lambda*exp(-lambda*x);
fth =@(x) (1/(sqrt(nu)*beta(0.5,0.5*nu)))*((1+((x.^2)./nu)).^(-0.5*(nu+1)));


figure
subplot(1,2,1)
plot(Xrng,fexph(Xrng),'k-')
subplot(1,2,2)
plot(Yrng,fth(Yrng),'b-')
```